# CSV-parse npm library, returns "Number of columns is inconsistent"

Tags: node.js, csv

I want to parse a csv file with csv-parse. At this moment, I can parse a file with header if there is not a caption at the first row of the file. So for example my file is like this:

```
Item1;Item2:Item3
Test1;Test2;Test3
```

But I need to be able to skip the first rows, because the actual data is like this:

```
This is a file with items
Items are stored below:
Item1;Item2:Item3
Test1;Test2;Test3
```

So I am in need to skip the first rows. csv-parse can do this with the from: option. But when I use this it will return an error that the Number of columns is inconsistent. This is true, because the first few rows are text, so only one column. But csv-parse will not ingnore the first few rows when I set for example from: 4 as an option.

My code:

```js
 var fs = require('fs');
 var parse = require('csv-parse');

    
    var parser = parse({delimiter: ';', from: 2}, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }
        var keys = data.shift();
        var objects = data.map(function(values) {
            return keys.reduce(function(o, k, i) {
                o[k] = values[i];
                return o;
            }, {});
        });
        console.log(objects);
    });

    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(parser);
```

Thank you in advance,

Sven